# When I Seed pbf tiles,the tile number is unusually,why?

Tags: geoserver

I create a shpfile Datastore then publish it.

I seed the pbf tiles using GWC,but tiles number is less than normal ,which meaning lacking amount of the tiles.

I have installed vectortiles plugin and gwc-sqlite plugin.

But however I use "File BlobStore" or "MBTiles BlobStore" It generated the same wrong count of tiles.And when I request the xyz url ,It can generate this tile normally.

The geoserver log did not indicate any useful infomation which did not include ERROR log information.

I have set all log Level.They are the same result.

My configuraion of "Metatiling factors" is 4X4.

When I changed this configuration to 1X1,It can generate the normal and right tiles.

I have test this case in 2.22.0 and 2.23.0 ,the problem cause the same.

Any clues appreciate.

Best regurds.